# Global jquery selector caching not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of jQuery selectors which is used all over the file which contains lots of functions. For this, I cached the jQuery selectors in top of the js file(globally) and the file itself is being loaded in `<head>` tag of an HTML code as

```
 var validationAlertPayment = $('#validationAlertPayment'),
     owner = $('#owner'),
     cardNumber = $('#cardNumber'),
     cardNumberField = $('#card-number-field'),
     CVV = $("#cvv"),
     mastercard = $("#mastercard"),
     confirmButton = $('#submitCCDetails'),
     editCCButton = $('#editCCDetails'),
     visa = $("#visa"),
     amex = $("#amex"),
     cc_verified_icon = $('#cc_verified_icon'),
     cc_month = $("#cc_month"),
     cc_year = $("#cc_year"),
     edit_payment_block = $('#edit-payment-block'),
     pay_now = $('#pay-now'),
     serviceRequestNo = $('#serviceRequestNo'),
     serviceReqLabel = $('#serviceReqLabel'),
     serviceRequestKey = $('#serviceRequestKey'),
     requestNumber = $('#requestNumber'),
     chat_Lines = $('#chatLines'),
     tranStepIcon = $('#transition-step-icon'),
     transitionArea = $("#transitionArea"),
     red_runway = $('#red_runway'),
     transition_label = $("#transition-label"),
     paymentIcon = $('#paymentIcon'),
     confirmIcon = $('#confirmIcon'),
     red_anim = $('#red-anim'),
     runway5 = $('#runway5'),
     confirmLine = $('#confirmLine'),
     paymentLine = $('#paymentLine'),
     title_greeting = $('#title_greeting'),
     runway1 = $('#runway1'),
     typeOfClaimLine = $('#typeOfClaimLine'),
     offerLine = $('#offerLine'),
     runway2 = $('#runway2'),
     runway3 = $('#runway3'),
     runway4 = $('#runway4'),
     typeOfClaimIcon = $('#typeOfClaimIcon'),
     offerIcon = $('#offerIcon'),
     shippingIcon = $('#shippingIcon'),
     shippingLine = $('#shippingLine'),
     estimated_wait_time = $('#estimated-wait-time'),
     offlineMsg = $('#offlineMsg'),
     chatWindow = $('#chatWindow'),
     appHistory = $('#appHistory'),
     attachment_div = $('.attachment-div'),
     appTransitions = $("#appTransitions"),
     delivery_address = $("#delivery_address"),
     delivery_date = $("#delivery_date"),
     toggleButton = $('#toggleButton'),
     transition_bar = $("#transition-bar"),
     offerredImageId = $("#offerredImageId"),
     offerPopupId = $("#offerPopupId"),
     popupTitleId = $("#popupTitleId"),
     chatWindowMessageMainDiv = $("#chatWindowMessageMainDiv"),
     chatMessageHeader = $("#chatMessageHeader"),
     confirmationDetails = $("#confirmationDetails"),
     deliveryDateTitle = $("#deliveryDateTitle"),
     shippingCodeTitle = $("#shippingCodeTitle"),
     confirmAddressId = $("#confirmAddressId"),
     offerTitle = $("#offerTitle"),
     confirmMakeModelId = $("#confirmMakeModelId"),
     customerVerificationIcon = $('#customerVerificationIcon'),
     mobileAppBody = $("#mobileAppBody");
```

Yes it is lots of caching..

But now when I am trying to use few of these variables in some some functions in the same file, I do not get the selector for the executionof any jQuery methods in functions. for example `transitionArea = $("#transitionArea")`. I get `undefined` when I log the variable

**Updated:** The selector variables which are not working are populated on DOM dynamically on a particular event. after the page load

Can someone help me understand the behaviour and how can I make this work?

**Note** I am using jQuery 3.2.1 and page is not intended get refreshed/reloaded after first load.

Comment: You should provide more info (or code). Where are You declaring variables, where are You loading js file, etc. Variable declaration is not enough

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Updated as per your suggestion

Comment: If it's not wraped in `$(document).ready()` then Your DOM is not yet available in `<head>` section. Move it to footer, or wrap with document.ready

Comment: Does it mean, the complete code of js file needs to be kept in `$(document).ready()` or just variable declarations? Also when you talked about DOM, I have updated the question.. please revisit

Comment: Variable declarations and functions that depend on DOM should be wrapped inside a `ready`-function. This function executes automatically when DOM is fully loaded. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @OMTheEternity the entire code should follow variable declarations in `$.ready`, as the variables are scoped in that method. Didn't see the rest of your code (put it here please), but probably that's why it's reading undefined as they don't see them.